# Use Docker secret value inside docker-compose.yml configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

We are using Docker swarm to deploy services. We would like to use Docker swarm secrets to store sensitive data (certificate passwords). Is it possible to use Docker secret value inside `docker-compose.yml` file? Docker client version is `20.10.6`, Docker engine version is `19.03.12`.

First, we create secret on the host:

```sh
printf 'ThisIsCertificatePassword123' | docker secret create CertificatePassword -
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: myimage:0.0.1
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+443;http://+80
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 443
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: # how can we use value of CertificatePassword here?
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /https/certificate.pfx
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

secrets:
  CertificatePassword:
    external: true
```

We deploy the stack with:

```sh
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml MyApplication
```

How can we use value of Docker secret `CertificatePassword` inside `docker-compose.yml` (at `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password`)?

Answer (score 0):

The community standard has been to support reading every environment variable directly: "FOO" and indirectly "FOO_FILE" where the _FILE variant is a path to a file containing FOO.

So,

```sh
SA_PASSWORD_FILE = /var/run/secrets/sql-password
SA_PASSWORD = Password123
```

should be equivalent, assuming that `/var/run/secrets/sql-password` contains `Password123`.

Now, I don't know that ASPNetCore Configuration supports this out the box and adding it doesn't seem trivial.